# SUMIF SQL MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [doc type], [Open Amount],
    [customer number],
    COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber,
    SUM(IIF([Open Amount]>'0', [Open Amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos,
    SUM(IIF([Open Amount]<'0', [Open Amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg       
FROM
(
    SELECT d.[customer number] & d.[membership number] AS CustMemb,
    d.[customer number],
    agg.[Open Amount],
    agg.[doc type],
    SUM(agg.[TotalSubOpenAmount]) AS SumOpenAmount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [doc type],
        [customer number],
        SUM([Open Amount]) AS TotalSubOpenAmount
        FROM data
        WHERE [doc type] = 'RU' 
        GROUP BY [doc type], [customer number], [Open Amount]
    ) agg
    INNER JOIN [data] d                                   
    ON  d.[customer number] = agg.[customer number]
    GROUP  BY d.[customer number] & d.[membership number],
    d.[customer number],
    agg.[doc type],
    agg.[Open Amount]
) AS sub
GROUP BY [doc type], [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

I am getting a `Parameter Input` on MS Access - Open Amount.

How do I reference the open amount in the from query?

Comment: `agg` subquery has no `[Open Amount]` column. Do you mean `TotalSubOpenAmount` ?

Comment: its likely because youre not using the alias 'sub' on youre [Open Amount] references in your iif functions. One of my most recent pet peeves is declaring an alais on an object and never using it appropriately. I mean when you have nested queries like this and you reference a column that is in each, how do you expect the compiler to magically know which one you are referring too?

Comment: And not to mention Serg is correct, agg subquery does not have open amount.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What would correct referencing look like here then?

Comment: @AbdelAziz AbdelLatef - Thank your for your help. 'Your query does not include the specified expression 'Open Amount' as part of an aggerate function' - Error message